# Resize images to be fullscreen with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you resize images to be fullscreen with javascript in the same way you can with flash?

Ive found this link but its for an entire plugin with slideshow, etc not just the feature I need for a more custom design:
http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

And this plugin seems to only with with background images: 
http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html

Ideally id like to do this with jQuery.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of a basic implementation. It accounts for resizing of the window, but doesn't account for any focus point of the image and so the focus point could fall out of view for oddly-sized windows.

http://jsbin.com/okizi5

Edit: I forgot to point that that the width/height attributes on the image are necessary in this version for all browsers (notably Safari) to calculate the aspect ratio of the image. If your image is to be dynamic and the dimensions are not available then these could be calculated within the 'load' function bound to the window.

Comment: Hi amustill, could you explain how the code works? Is the js detecting the browser's window size, and then making the image that size? Or, is there more going on than that? Thanks

Comment: A tiny bit more than that. It firstly calculates the image dimensions and aspect ratio so that we use that to calculate the the final image dimensions. The resizeImage() function then detects the browser dimensions, checks the aspect ratio of that and adjusts the image dimensions accordingly so that it's always in proportion.

Comment: The images will actually be in divs, so could I use jQuery to get the div size and apply it as css to the image's width? The images will will be in the html not background images. As I recall, If you set the height of an image with css to auto and then change the width, it will resize keeping the correct dimensions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I don't see why you can't, really. You can use JavaScript, and its DOM interface, to modify the style properties of an image to resize an image. You don't even need a heavy library like jQuery; it's all native.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#myImgId').width($(window).width());
    $('#myImgId').height($(window).height());
});
```

It will not maintain the aspect ratio...

Comment: Thanks, but ill need to keep the aspect ratio.